# Finding out L1 L2 L3 cache details in our system

Tags: caching, assembly, x86

Is it possible to find out the full and detailed behavior of the cache present in our desktop machine - details related to the digital schematic of the cache or the amount of compiler level optimizations present or hardware prefetching, etc.

My doubt is more on the lines of finding out what sort of optimizations have been done to the L1,L2 & L3 caches in our system. I am currently programming in x86 assembly to find out how the L1 I and D caches, are working with the CPU and the unified L2 cache, respectively.

Does Intel or any other hardware manufacturer provide some manual regarding the behavior of their caches?? If so please provide some links

Or - is it that whatever we learn in the basic architecture course (in computer engineering), is what is implemented by Intel???

Thanks alot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Intel or any other hardware manufacturer provide some manual regarding the behavior of their caches??

http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/papers/cache6.pdf
http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf

Hope those links help. The former is a detailed approach to how the cache works in a Pentium processor:

> The first part gives an overview of cache, while the
>   second part explains how the Pentium Processor implements cache.

The latter is an extensive developer's manual for Intel 64 & IA-32 architectures which also covers cache memories.